# Elasticsearch query is extremely slow and not efficient

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to the elastic search concept and I am exposed to this concept because of a tool. This  tool has now introduced Elasticsearch for fetching the license usage details of the tool user.

The version of elastic search installed is 6.4.3. The product by default provides a Powershell script which i have tried to add few filters to fetch the license consumption by dates and feature.

I would require to publish a report with the license consumption details every month. The below Powershell script does not finish executing even after 12 hours and the output file size is greater than 2 GB and still growing.

Any help in fine tuning this script would be of great help.

I use a batch file with the below content:

```
powershell.exe -File .\query.ps1 -hostname "<XXX>" -port 9200 -outputFilePath D:\LicenseUsageTracker\OutputFile.json -startDate 2019-12-10 -endDate 2019-12-11 -featureName XXX
```

The content of query.ps1 is as follows

```
param( [String]$hostname, [Int32]$port, [String]$outputFilePath, [STRING]$startDate, [STRING]$endDate ,$featureName)

function CheckStatusCode {
    param( [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject]$response )
    if ($response.StatusCode -ne 200) {
        Write-host ("ERROR RESPONSE: STATUS: " + ($response.StatusCode) + "; CONTENT: " + ($response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json))
        return $false;
    }
    return $true;
}

function AddHits {
    param( [System.Object[]]$hits, [String]$path )
    If (-not (Test-Path $path -PathType Leaf)) {
        New-Item $path -ItemType file -Force
    }
    $comma = "";

    Write-host ("Writing " + $hits.length + " search results...")
    ForEach ($hit In $hits) {
        Add-Content -Path $path -Value ($comma + ($hit._source | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation))
        $comma = "";

    }
    Write-host ("done.")
}

If (Test-Path $outputFilePath -PathType Leaf) {
    $overwrite = read-host ("File '" + $outputFilePath + "' exists already. Overwrite? (yes/no)");
    If ($overwrite -ne "yes") {
        Write-host ("Exiting script.")
        return;
    } else {
        Write-host ("Overwriting file '" + $outputFilePath + "'");
        Remove-Item -Path $outputFilePath
    }
} else {
    Write-host ("Writing to file '" + $outputFilePath + "'");
}

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://${hostname}:${port}/usageinfo/_search?scroll=2m&filter_path=_scroll_id,hits.hits._source" -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Body ('{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timeStamp": {
              "gte": "' + $startDate + '",
              "lte": "' + $endDate + '"
                     }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "featureName":"' + $featureName + '"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10000
 }');

if (-not (CheckStatusCode($response))) {
    return;
}

$jsonContent = ($response.Content  | ConvertFrom-Json);
$scrollId = $jsonContent._scroll_id;
$hits = $jsonContent.hits.hits;
AddHits $hits $outputFilePath;


while ($hits.length -gt 0) {

    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://${hostname}:${port}/_search/scroll?filter_path=_scroll_id,hits.hits._source" -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Body ('{ "scroll" : "2m", "scroll_id" : "' + $scrollId + '"}');
    if (-not (CheckStatusCode($response))) {
        return;
    }

    $scrollId = ($response.Content  | ConvertFrom-Json)._scroll_id;
    $hits = ($response.Content  | ConvertFrom-Json).hits.hits;
    If ($hits.Length -ne 0) {
        AddHits $hits $outputFilePath;
    }

};
```

Comment: It looks like the script downloads all matching documents. How many documents are there in Elasticsearch? It could be that there are just too many.

Comment: Hi Nikolay ,  this is part of the vendor product , so i am not sure how many documents are there. Is there a way i can find that out using a query?

Comment: Also i want the query to first filter by timestamp range ,and then apply the feature match on the filtered output. I am  not sure if the above script is doing that

Comment: You can get the count with same query you have inside the script, using curl, and replace `_search` endpoint with [`_count`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html). Also from the code the query should be filtering on date (the `range` part).

Comment: hi Nikolay, could you please help me understand how to use curl in this script.

Comment: I thought it would be easier to use it outside the script. Curl or any other tool to make http requests will do.

Comment: Hi Nikolay ,  i would need the data and not the count. Also i am running this on a windows machine using powershell , so i dont think curl is an option.